# How does systemctl suspend work?

Tags: systemd, suspend

From the systemctl manpage:

> suspend
>
> Suspend the system. This will trigger activation of the special target unit suspend.target. This command is asynchronous, and will
>   return after the suspend operation is successfully enqueued. It will
>   not wait for the suspend/resume cycle to complete.

On my system the `suspend.target` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Suspend
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=systemd-suspend.service
After=systemd-suspend.service
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
```

If I look at the `man:systemd.special(7)` listed there I get find this:

> suspend.target
>              A special target unit for suspending the system. This pulls in sleep.target.

If I dig more into `systemd-suspend.service` I get:

> systemd-suspend.service is a system service that is pulled in by
>   suspend.target and is responsible for the actual system suspend.
>
> ...
>
> Internally, this service will echo a string like "mem" into
>   /sys/power/state, to trigger the actual system suspend. What exactly
>   is written where can be configured in the "[Sleep]" section of
>   /etc/systemd/sleep.conf or a sleep.conf.d file.

The documentation on `sleep.conf` tells me:

> The default configuration is defined during compilation, so a
>   configuration file is only needed when it is necessary to deviate from
>   those defaults.

There is no `sleep.conf` on my system so it must be using the compiled defaults.  I can't figure out what those are.

What are the exact commands being sent to `/sys/power/state` and friends by `systemctl suspend` by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The defaults are [`"mem", "standby", "freeze"`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/shared/sleep-config.c#L72) (the last two and the ability to configure sleep modes have been [added in 2013](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2013-May/010799.html) so they might not be available on older setups).
The manual page you quoted describes how it's done, namely `systemd-suspend.service` writes

> ... a string like `"mem"` into `/sys/power/state`, to
>   trigger the actual system suspend.

For more information about the sleep states and the `sysfs` interface that can be used by user space to control those states consult the official docs: [*System Sleep States*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking in sleep.c not sleep-config.c and not finding what I needed.  I always appreciate an answer that points to the actual source code!